Helm chart errors with index of untyped nil
I have a use case to check if a particular key is empty. the logic is below:
{{- if or (ne $k "zzz") (quote $.Values.abc.xyz.ppp | empty ) }}

This works fine if .Values.abc.xyz is present, but if xyz is missing, this fails with error:

error calling index: index of untyped nil

I looked at few other stack overflow, but could not get it to work. I tried something like default dict, but that did not work too.
{{- $overrides := index .Values.abc.xyz | default dict }}


Any pointers would be helpful.

The problem here is that if a key like xyz doesn't exist in either the chart's values.yaml file or the user-provided values, the Go lookup rules cause .Values.abc.xyz to evaluate to nil and not a map, and you can't navigate further in it.
The default dict trick you mention uses the default function to replace any "falsey" value with some default, where dict is an empty dictionary if you call it with no parameters.
{{- $abc := $.Values.abc | default dict }}
{{- $xyz := $abc.xyz | default dict }}
{{- if or (ne $k "zzz") (empty $xyz.ppp) }}

The dig extension function is also designed for this case.  It takes a sequence of nested-dict keys as parameters plus a default, and knows how to stop if it sees a missing key.
{{- if or (ne $k "zzz") ($.Values | dig "abc" "xyz" "ppp" "" | empty) }}

